How to get blob tags in Laravel
How can I get the tags of my blobs using Laravel ?
I d'ont know what to try that's why I'm a little bit stick
As you know PHP is not supported by azure so I can't find any clues in the documentation if anyone have any ideas to share I would really appreciate that so much


get blob tags in Laravel

You can use the below steps to get the blob index using Laravel PHP application.
first create Laravel application using below command,
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel get-blob-tags

Create the blob controller with below command:
php artisan make:controller BlobController

Now paste the below code in BlobController.php file.
Code:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;

class BlobController extends Controller
{
    public function fetchBlobIndexTags()
    {
        // URL of the blob with SAS token
        $url = 'https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container name>/<blob name>?comp=tags&<sas token>';
        
        // Create a Guzzle HTTP client
        $client = new Client();
        
        try {
            // Send a GET request to the URL
            $response = $client->get($url);
            
            // Get the body of the response
            $body = $response->getBody();
            
            
            $contentType = $response->getHeaderLine('Content-Type');
            
            if (strpos($contentType, 'xml') !== false) {
                $xml = simplexml_load_string($body);
                $json = json_encode($xml);
                $tags = json_decode($json, true);
            } else {
                $tags = json_decode($body, true);
            }
            
            // Return the blob index tags
            return response()->json($tags);
            
        } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
            // Handle exceptions if any
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Error fetching blob index tags: ' . $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }
}

In your project change the routes/web.php like below:
use App\Http\Controllers\BlobController;

Route::get('/fetch-blob-tags', [BlobController::class, 'fetchBlobIndexTags']);

Run with php artisan serve command in the terminal to get the azure blob index tag.
Output:


Reference:
Get Blob Tags (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn
